# [palantir-foundry][slate] Foundry Slate - HTML widget Row selection

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

In Slate I have an HTML widget with 'n' rows. I would like to select/deselect some rows by clicking on each row and then mark them as, say 'top variables' if selection is made and visualize them on the application with some labels or color code on the row.

Is it possible to do via Slate UI. Any pointers here would be greatly helpful. Thanks!

I have not tried doing much as I'm unsure of how to do it. I just tried to add an 'add' icon next to each row and on click of the icon be able to select the row but seem to be not working as expected.

Note: What I was trying to do was something that appears while we make tag selection to add tags to Quiver analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the "Table" widget in Foundry. It allows Data selection and offers configuring values such as "Multi-select", sorting, paging and a lot of other features.

Comment: For managing the display in HTML or Table widgets, I'd also recommend looking at the Slate reference examples in the /Foundry Training and Resources/Reference Examples in your Foundry instance.